# SQL to get an daily average from month total

Tags: sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a table that lists month totals (targets)

```
person      total                 month       
----------- --------------------- ----------- 
1001        114.00                201005      
1001        120.00                201006      
1001        120.00                201007      
1001        120.00                201008      
.
1002        114.00                201005      
1002        222.00                201006      
1002        333.00                201007      
1002        111.00                201008      
.
.
```

but month is an integer(!)

I also have another table that has a list of working days (calendar)

```
tran_date               day_type
----------------------- ---------------------------------
1999-05-01 00:00:00.000 WEEKEND
1999-05-02 00:00:00.000 WEEKEND
1999-05-03 00:00:00.000 WORKING_DAY
1999-05-04 00:00:00.000 WORKING_DAY

1999-06-01 00:00:00.000 .....
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is get a list of dates with the average for that day based on the number of days in the month where day_type is 'WORKING_DAY' /  the month's total.

so if I had say 20 working days in 201005 then I'd get an average of 114/20 on each working day, while the other days would be 0.

somthing like

```
person   tran_date               day_avg
-------  ----------------------- ---------------------------------
1001     2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 0
1001     2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 0
1001     2010-05-03 00:00:00.000 114/2 (as there are two working days)
1001     2010-05-04 00:00:00.000 114/2 (as there are two working days)
.
.
.
```

It has to be done as a CTE as this is a limitation of the target system (I can only do one statement)
I can start off with (Dates to

```
WITH 
Dates AS
(
    SELECT CAST('19990501' as datetime) TRAN_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TRAN_DATE + 1
    FROM Dates
    WHERE TRAN_DATE + 1 <= CAST('20120430' as datetime)
),
Targets as
(
   select CAST(cast(month as nvarchar) + '01' as dateTime) mon_start, 
            DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(cast(month as nvarchar) + '01' as dateTime)) mon_end, 
             total
   from targets
)
select ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data (may vary):

```
select * into #totals from (
select '1001' as person, 114.00  as total, 199905 as month union
select '1001', 120.00, 199906 union
select '1001', 120.00, 199907 union
select '1001', 120.00, 199908  

) t

select * into #calendar from (
select cast('19990501' as datetime) as tran_date, 'WEEKEND' as day_type union
select '19990502', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990503', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990504', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990505', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990601', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990602', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990603', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990604', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990605', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990606', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990701', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990702', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990703', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990704', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990801', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990802', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990803', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990804', 'WEEKEND' union
select '19990805', 'WORKING_DAY' union
select '19990901', 'WORKING_DAY'
) t
```

Select statement, it returns 0 if the day is 'weekend' or not exists in `calendar` table. Please keep in mind that `MAXRECURSION` is a value between 0 and 32,767.

```
;with dates as ( 
    select cast('19990501' as datetime) as tran_date 
    union all 
    select dateadd(dd, 1, tran_date) 
    from dates where dateadd(dd, 1, tran_date) <= cast('20010101' as datetime) 
) 
select t.person , d.tran_date, (case when wd.tran_date is not null then t.total / w_days else 0 end) as day_avg 
from dates d 
left join #totals t on  
    datepart(yy, d.tran_date) * 100 + datepart(mm, d.tran_date) = t.month 
left join ( 
        select datepart(yy, tran_date) * 100 + datepart(mm, tran_date) as month, count(*) as w_days 
        from #calendar 
        where day_type = 'WORKING_DAY' 
        group by datepart(yy, tran_date) * 100 + datepart(mm, tran_date) 
) c on t.month = c.month  
left join #calendar wd on d.tran_date = wd.tran_date and wd.day_type = 'WORKING_DAY' 
where t.person is not null
option(maxrecursion 20000)
```

Comment: I updated you answer to get rid of unwanted results. Thanks for this - it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the number of working days per month in a subquery.  Only the subquery would have to use `group by`.  For example:

```
select   t.person
,        wd.tran_date
,        t.total / m.WorkingDays as day_avg
from     @Targets t
join     @WorkingDays wd
on       t.month =  convert(varchar(6), wd.tran_date, 112) 
left join
        (
        select  convert(varchar(6), tran_date, 112) as Month
        ,       sum(case when day_type = 'WORKING_DAY' then 1 end) as WorkingDays
        from    @WorkingDays
        group by
                convert(varchar(6), tran_date, 112)
        ) as  m
on      m.Month = t.month
```

[Working example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119735/)
For the "magic number" 112 in `convert`, see [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Good answer - I have to pick the other one as this ommits the days where the avg is not to be applied (Non Working days). Thanks thought, I've learned new tricks from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, the following query should do it:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ISNULL(
        (
            SELECT total
            FROM targets
            WHERE
                MONTH(tran_date) = month - ROUND(month, -2)
                AND c1.day_type = 'WORKING_DAY'
        ) /
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM calendar c2
            WHERE
                MONTH(c1.tran_date) = MONTH(c2.tran_date)
                AND c2.day_type = 'WORKING_DAY'
        ),
        0
    ) day_avg
FROM
    calendar c1
```

In plain English:

- For each row in `calendar`,
- get the total of the corresponding month if this row is a working day (otherwise get NULL),
- get the number of working days in the same month
- and divide them.
- Finally, convert the NULL (of non-working days) into 0.

Comment: Thank you, but this fails when I have more that one distinct person. Sorry My mistake in the question I should have made it clear. Nice try though. I've learned a lot from the explanation.